# Guess my number

Tags: python, python-3.x

It prints "Sorry, I did not understand your input..." everytime.

If I remove the exception part for the input to be just the integer, it works just fine.

Here's the code:

```
num= input('Please think of a number between 0 and 100!')

a=int(num)

if type(a)=="int":
    low=0
    high=100
    mid= (low+high)/2

    while round(mid) != a:

        print("Is your secret number", round(mid),"?")

        x=input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")

        if x=="h":
            high=round(mid)
        elif x=="l":
            low=round(mid)
        elif x=="c":
            break
        else:
            print("Sorry, I did not understand your input.")

        mid=(low+high)/2

    if round(mid) ==a:
        print("Is your secret number", round(mid),"?")

        y=input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")

    print("Game over. Your secret number was:", round(mid))  

else:

    print("Sorry, I did not understand your input...")
```

Comment: I think we should have a sub site named "guess number". Why there are so many people who are working on guess number game and face the same issue but don't know just search it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because of `type(a) == 'int'` part. Use `type(a) == int` or `isinstance(a, int)` instead. With that said, the statement serves no purpose as `int(num)` is going to raise exception beforehand in case of an invalid integer.

```
# First make sure if the number is even a valid integer before casting.
if num.isdigit():
    a = int(num)
    ...
else:
    print("Sorry, I did not understand your input")
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't get past the first if statement

```
>>>type(1)=='int'
False
```

You could just use `isinstance` (although, at this point in your code, it can't possibly not be an integer)

```
if isinstance(a, int):
```

Comment: But type(a) should have been an int isn't it? Why such?

Comment: @AnushPoudel - Because you're comparing vs the *string* "int", not vs the type

Comment: I corrected the code and it worked fine on my machine.
But when I sent the code for review on edx. I gave me 0/10 with this output:  
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'l'

*** ERROR: Failing on first line.
Expected: Please think of a number between 0 and 100!
Your code generated: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'l'. ***

Comment: @AnushPoudel That's happening because `int(num)` would raise an exception in case of a non integer value. Try checking `isdigit` first.